# Condition based on segue identifier

Tags: ios, if-statement

I have a small amount of code from which I want only a certain view controller to use. The view controller shares a class with another controller.

Is it possible to target the if statement based on the push segue identifier?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:@"Added to Routine!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

I do have a IF statement within my `prepareForSegue:` method but I wish to have one within my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSightingDetails"])
```

I have looked around but can't see anything directly associated with this.

This should be something that is fairly simple I would of thought.

Comment: No, the segue is only accessible in prepare for segue. It doesn't even make sense to access it outside of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have specified different cell identifiers for your cells in your storyboard. You could get the cell in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and check its `reuseIdentifier`. The Code could be something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Identifier1"]) {
        // Do something
    } else if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Identifier2"]) {
        // Do something different
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Much simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a property, something like `@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldAlert;` and set its value in `prepareForSeague`, then you can refer to it later.